# Invalid postback or callback argument on dropdowns

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

[image]

I have this two radio buttons

on click of ***ship to above address*** Left dropdowns values will be gone to right one

[image]

All working fine but when i click on button submit of this page then I have this error

---

***Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.***

---

Obviously i know if i do **eventvalidation='false'** then it will work but is there anything else that can solve this problem with **eventvalidation='true'**?

For a moment i think that binding of dropdown is wrong so i tried diff codes in javscript but same result i am getting from it my javscript code looks like

---

```
 $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingPostcode").html($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlpostcode").html());
   $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingState").html($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlstate").html());
```

---

Also i tried

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingPostcode').innerHTML=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingPostcode').innerHTML+document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlpostcode').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingState').innerHTML=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingState').innerHTML+document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlstate').innerHTML;
```

Any help would be appreciated?

### One thing to note that if i don't bind dropdowns with javascript then that error does not appears

Comment: yes this happens when you update state through ajax.

Comment: I am not updating through ajax i already have values at left and i just clone that values to right one @tariq

Comment: @dholakiyaankit: you need to do that on the server-side. cloning at client-side will definitely cause event validation to kick-off.

Comment: ammmmm is that so? I don't want to go for serverside for two drops :(]

Comment: @abhitalks but textboxes are working fine

Comment: @dholakiyaankit: textboxes will work fine because they are meant to collect text. but dropdowns have pre-populated options, which if changed at client-side will cause event validation to kick-in for sure. only selection is meant to be collected, not the options themselves. so, effectively there are only two ways: (1) client-side manipulation with event-validation turned off, or (2) server-side manipulation to be safe.

Comment: @abhitalks I think you are right let me anylize first what to do

Comment: @abhitalks thanks i have done it little bit diffrently check my ans but thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @abhitalks ya i have to go for serverside code because of the prepopulated code done by the dropdowns and i don't want to do server side coding so now i have done like this

at page load time i have binded right side drops also like this

[image]

So when user clicks on Ship to above address then i just have to select the drops like this

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingPostcode").val($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlpostcode").val());
 $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlshippingState").val($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlstate").val());
```

And it works great with event `validation=true`

So after clicking i just play with  selection of dropdowns like this when clicked on above address will be look like

[image]

Comment: Good workaround! You may also want to read here (a bit old but good reading) on this issue: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/20/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument.aspx